# How to convert string with bytes value back to bytes?

Tags: python, ascii

I have a program where I write the python check_output output on a file. I forgot to set the encoding to "utf-8" and all the outputs are in bytes. I have written these bytes values on a file. What I have now on my files is some string like " b' math \xf0\x9d " containing both ASCII and hex. How can I get just ASCII values and convert the hex values such as \xf0\x9d to their original values?

To answer this I need a way to convert the string with bytes values back to bytes. In the example below, opt is bytes, temp is a string. How can I convert temp to opt again?

More details: This is the code that I originally wanted to run. what I get in variable opt has hex values. I was hoping by converting it to a string, I would get rid of them but it is not working.

```
latex = "a+b"
opt = check_output(["latexmlmath", "--quiet", "--cmml=-", latex])
temp = str(opt)
# also tried
temp = str(opt).encode("utf-8")
```

The opt and temp values are:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="a+b" display="block">\n  <apply>\n    <plus/>\n    <ci>\xf0\x9d\x91\x8e</ci>\n    <ci>\xf0\x9d\x91\x8f</ci>\n  </apply>\n</math>\n'
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="a+b" display="block">\n  <apply>\n    <plus/>\n    <ci>\xf0\x9d\x91\x8e</ci>\n    <ci>\xf0\x9d\x91\x8f</ci>\n  </apply>\n</math>\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted `opt.decode('utf-8')`; calling `str` on a `bytes` object without a second (`encoding`) argument just gets the `repr` of the `bytes` object. If you have data from such a conversion available, you can convert it back to the original `bytes` object [with `ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), then perform the intended `decode` on the result. Example:

```
import ast

baddata = 'b\'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\\n<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="a+b" display="block">\\n  <apply>\\n    <plus/>\\n    <ci>\\xf0\\x9d\\x91\\x8e</ci>\\n    <ci>\\xf0\\x9d\\x91\\x8f</ci>\\n  </apply>\\n</math>\\n\''
gooddata = ast.literal_eval(baddata).decode('utf-8')
print(gooddata)
```

outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="a+b" display="block">
  <apply>
    <plus/>
    <ci></ci>
    <ci></ci>
  </apply>
</math>
```